# PHP удаление не нужных сессий

Tags: php, сессия

Сейчас опишу не стандартную ситуацию, чтобы понять в чем собсвенно проблема.

1. Пользователь авторизируется на сайте

   - Создается phpsessid
   - Создается кука с секретным ключем, для будущего автологина

А теперь, мы будучи авторизированными, удаляем мануально из браузера, phpsessid и заходим обратно на сайт.

Правильно, мы автологинимся, по куке с ключем, куку мы то оставили. При автологине, создается новая Phpsessid сессия ! И тут внимание ! Старая Phpsessid сессия остается !!!

Вопрос в том ! Как узнать используется эта сессия кем-то или нет ? На выходе у нас в папке сессий, получается, 2 файла сессий, один из которых не используется. Но как его удалить ?

Comment: Не переживай, РНР всё удалит

Comment: У меня вопрос в другом, как PHP знает, используется она или нет ? По сути мы создали как бы используемую сессию, а удалением ее из браузера, отрезали от нее пользователя и та  осталась лежать сама по себе на сервере.

Comment: Как РНР узнает, написано по ссылке

Comment: Из ссылки я понял что PHP считывает время создания сессии (файла) и если он не обновлялся X минут, он его удаляет, верно ? Если да, тогда понял как работает и вопросов пока что больше нет.